# I'm trying to list all containers that have port 80 or say 443 published

Tags: docker

The question is very simple, How to list containers that have ports 80 and 443 published?

have gone through docker documentation, but couldn't find much. 
- docker port containerID => this will show the port details for specific Container

Comment: Why not just docker `docker ps |grep "80/tcp\|443/tcp" | awk '{print $1}'`?

Comment: I was expecting any docker command to do it.. any way.. this works thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of [--filter](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/#filtering) option of [docker ps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps) command.

```
docker ps --filter "publish=80" --filter "publish=443"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of `format` and `filter`

```
docker ps -a --format 'table {{ .Names }} \t {{ .Ports }}' --filter publish=443 --filter publish=80
```

or using `expose` filter:

```
docker ps -a --format 'table {{ .Names }} \t {{ .Ports }}' --filter expose=443
```

get a range of `posrts`:

```
docker ps --format 'table {{ .Names }} \t {{ .Ports }}' --filter expose=8000-8080/tcp
```